# Compile member only if function is called

Tags: c++, oop

my code looks like this.

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    void use(){}
};

class B
{
public:
    A a;
    void useA(){}
};
```

Can I let the compiler remove `B::a` if `B::useA()` can never be called?
so if b::useA() is not in the code, then in the compiler output there will be no A object.

why? i am coding a game engine. if no 'renderable3d' are drawn, the prgram will execute faster and take less memory if no '3dlayer' is created. i can use something like '#define USE_NO_3D', but that cuases only confusion in my opinion.

os: window 10 64 bit
compiler: mingw g++

Comment: Do you really mean conditionally  'compile'  or do you want `B::a` only be instantiated after `useA` was called? For the latter you might just make it of type `A*`, initialize with `nullptr` and allocate it within `useA`

Comment: Compilation is before any runtime call so you can't determine if any call is done in compilation time. Isn't it XY problem? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: You could make `A` a template parameter of `B` (or possibly `B::useA`). The compiler will generate the relevant code only if `B<A>` (or `B::useA<A>()`) is present in your code at compile time (regardless of it being called at runtime or not).

Comment: Without more details, why does `a` need to be a member variable of `B` and not a local variable of the function `B::useA`? If it's only used in that function, you can just only put it in that function.

Comment: No idea *why* something should only be compiled or not, because it doesn't matter at all! You can more or less be sure that: The compiler inlines all and everything as long it is in one translation unit, you can be sure that not used code will be removed during link stage and you simply should not think about manual optimization at all! Your compiler is a good one... let him work. Trust!. BTW: As the question gives us no idea *why* something should be happen or not... I vote for close!

Comment: I can't think of a construct that would allow you to do this, even in a single translation unit. (I can at runtime, compile time is a different challenge altogether). Voted to reopen by the way. Are we not allowing interesting questions anymore?

Comment: Have a look at friend injection compile time programming if you are really motivated.

Comment: It can do what you want but is the work of the devil.